# Several numpy arrays with SWIG

Tags: c++, python, numpy, swig

I am using SWIG to pass numpy arrays from Python to C++ code:

```
%include "numpy.i"
%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (float* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(float* data, int n)};

class Class 
{
  public: 
  void test(float* data, int n)
  {
    //...
  }
};
```

and in Python:

```
c = Class()
a = zeros(5)
c.test(a)
```

This works, but how can I pass multiple numpy arrays to the same function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out the answer from a collegue of mine:

```
%apply (float* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(float* data1, int n1), (float* data2, int n2)};

class Class 
{
  public: 
  void test(float* data1, int n1, float* data2, int n2)
  {
    //...
  }
};
```

Now two numpy arrays are passed to Class::test.

Comment: you can shorten the apply directive a little bit by applying the typemap to both input pairs at the same time:

%apply (float* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(float* data1, int n1),
                                          (float* data2, int n2)};